# Can not add foreign key in laravel migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I'm almost sure its a silly problem but I am unable to see it.  I have read through dozen of sites and tutorials with not hope. I have simple migration that creates a new table and defines it.  I am trying to add a foreign key constraint to it but I get seemingly contradicting errors.

```
class CreateAlchemyPages extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::dropIfExists('alchemy_pages');
        Schema::create('alchemy_pages', function(Blueprint $nt)
        {
            $nt->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $nt->increments('id');
            $nt->integer('course_id');
            $nt->foreign('course_id')->references('ID')->on('Courses')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $nt->integer('parent_page_id')->unsigned();
            $nt->integer('navigation_order');
            $nt->string('full_title');
            $nt->string('short_title');
            $nt->string('page_info');
            $nt->integer('state');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        // Cleanup our tables            
    }
}
```

After running migrate, I get the following error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>       SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1022 Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-60d4_d54' (SQL: alter t   able
>   `alchemy_pages` add constraint alchemy_pages_course_id_foreign foreign
>   key (`course_id`) references `Courses` (`ID`) on delete cascade on
>   update cascade)

If I change it to this

```
//$nt->integer('course_id')->unsigned();
$nt->foreign('course_id')->references('ID')->on('Courses')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

It gives me the error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>       SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'course_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table
>   `alchemy_pages` add constraint alchemy_pages_course_id_foreign foreign
>   key (`course_id`) references `Courses` (`ID`) o   n delete cascade on
>   update cascade)

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you already have an index named "alchemy_pages_course_id_foreign" in your database. You can either delete it or pass your own name for the index as the second argument: `$tn->foreign('course_id', 'new_index_name')->references(...)`

Comment: Good call, there was actually a copy of the tables, renamed, that was using that same key.  Thanks!